# Move mouse in certain direction while holding key in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, input

I just started with C++ and I've been messing around with mouse movements in C++. I'm currently trying to get the mouse to forever move to the right while I'm holding down a key, and stop when I'm not.

The only way I can find to achieve anything similar to this is to use `GetAsyncKeyState` and `SetCursorPos`, but that would just instantly move my cursor to a certain position. I want the mouse to just keep moving to the right (or whatever direction) while a key is held down.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: you need to move your cursor to related position not absolute position (and maybe some `sleep` is needed)

Comment: @appleapple: You are confusing cause and effect. Moving the cursor shape does not magically generate mouse input. And since you can control the cursor with the keyboard as well, how should the system decide, which input to fake? You need to generate input. The cursor moving is just one of the observable effects.

Comment: @IInspectable I think OP don't need a mouse event be fired at all

Comment: @appleapple: Based on what information do you assume that applying an arbitrary restriction would be justifiable?

Comment: @IInspectable because OP don't request it, and it seems like OP just start using winapi

Comment: @appleapple: *"get the mouse to **forever** move to the right"* - `1` This never mentions the work *"cursor"*. `2` Once you hit the right edge of the display, you can no longer move the cursor any farther. However, you can still generate input that simulates mouse movement to the right. Even if not explicitly stated, the OP is looking to generate mouse **input**, not just cursor movement.

Answer (score -1):

[Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) for globally monitoring keyboard input, and [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) to generate mouse input.